# How can I get statistical columns in R?

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

I have a dataset with info of employees. I would like to add new column data$smedio with statistical info in each instance, for example the mean of its group. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
nombres<-c("Juan","Pedro","Alfonso","Luis") > ciudad<-c("Madrid","Barna","Barna","Madrid") 
dpto<-c("Finanzas","Produccion","Produccion","Produccion") 
salario<-c(25000,30000,28000,35000) 
data<-data.frame(nombres,ciudad,dpto,salario)
```

For example Pedro and Alfonso would have data$smedio with value equal (30000+28000)/2=29000. Both two the same value (because they have same dpto and same ciudad). Other instance values depend on each case.

I try create that new column with this sentence...

```
data$smedio<-data %>% group_by(data$ciudad, data$dpto) %>% summarize(mean(salario))
```

Buy I get that error:

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, smedio, value = list(`data$ciudad` = c(1L, : replacement has 3 rows, data has 4

Answer (score -1):

data %>% group_by(ciudad, dpto) %>% summarize(mean(salario))

Comment: Really would be: 
data<- data %>% group_by(ciudad,dpto) %>% 
  mutate(smedio.new = mean(salario))